# How to move singup\signin templates into dropdown menu?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I have a fixed navigation and I want to add dropdown box where users can singup\in (as Twitter uses).

I tried:

```
# project/tempates/signup.html
{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

  <p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

  <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ signupform.as_p }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
  </form>

{% endblock %}

# project/tempates/base.html
# ... a lot of basic stuff
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        {% include './signup.html' %}
# ... rest stuff
```

and in dropdown box I see just the text, link to signin, and the button for confirmation of the registration.

There are no fields to enter email and passwords. As I understand, this is because no access to the form, what usually is a views' jobs. How can I get workable dropdown forms?

Comment: Can you include your view in the post?

Comment: @MichaelFourre, it seems that here there is a problem. I found at SO (example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499449/django-allauth-login-signup-form-on-homepage ) and in internet ( http://notesbyanerd.com/joint-login-and-signup-django-allauth-view ) some views samples, but I have no idea how to connect them to dropdown form. Original views are here - https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py

Comment: But where is your view? Are you using the SignupView as a parent class?

Comment: @MichaelFourre, lets take for example the view that is already written at another SO thread. How to combine that view with dropdown menu?

Comment: Why don't you want to add your view? We can tell you how something might work with a view from another SO post but that might not be how it works in your situation. For one, since you can clearly see `login_form` is the name of the LoginForm instance, you'll refer to it as `login_form` in the view rather than `signupform` as you have. But I doubt your view uses the same name, so just post your view?

Comment: @MichaelFourre, sorry that I disturb you. Could you explain few things to me pls. 1. I do not understand, why I need to make my own views. Why I cant use `allauth` views directly? I do not want to change anything in `allauth`. I simpy want to move its template or form from separate page as `account/signup` to nav bar. 2. In order to get any apps form, it is needed to call views via url. I do not know, how to make this call to view from nav bar in order to get as a responce template or form. I want to have signup\login template\form as a dropdown block (not a link) on every site's page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After 2 days of internet digging I want to summarize what I found.

There are few ways:

**1. Use `<form action='some address here'>`**. The easiest way.

To check default `AllAuth` forms we need to:

```
# ./manage.py shell
>>> import allauth.account.forms as forms
>>> f = forms.LoginForm()
>>> print(f)
```

Below is edited version of `print(f)` which is added directly to base.html

```
<form action="{% url 'account_login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />

    <input id="id_login" name="login" placeholder="Username or e-mail" type="text" required />
    <input id="id_password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required />

    <label for="id_remember">Remember Me:</label>
    <input id="id_remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" />

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <a href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">Forgot Password?</a>
</form>
```

Method is based on the solution from ->[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page)<-

**2. Contex processor**

**a)** Make folder `your_project/your_app/context_processor`. Put there 2 files - `__init__.py` and `login_ctx.py`

**b)** In `login_ctx.py` add:

```
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

def login_ctx_tag(request):
    return {'loginctx': LoginForm()}
```

**c)** In project's `SETTINGS` add `your_app.context_processors.login_ctx.login_form_ctx' in`TEMPLATES` section. Something like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'your_app.context_processors.login_ctx.login_form_ctx',  # <- put your processor here 
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                # [...other processors...]
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**d)** In your `*.html` where you need add the next:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'account_login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
        {{ loginctx }}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    {# display something else here... (username?) #}
{% endif %}
```

**3. Template tag**

**a)** Make folder `your_project/your_app/templatetags`. Put there 2 files - `__init__.py` and `login_tag.py`

**b)** In `login_tag.py` add:

```
from django import template
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('profiles/true_login.html')
def login_form_tag(current_page=None):
    return {'loginform': LoginForm(),
            'redirect_to': current_page}
```

**c)** In `your_project/your_app/templates/your_app/` make file `login_form.html` with content:

```
{% load account  %}

{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'account_login' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
        {{ loginform }}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    {# display something else here... (username?) #}
{% endif %}
```

**d)** In any `*.html` you need, add at the top `{% load login_tag %}` and in the needed place add `{% login_form_tag request.get_full_path %}`

---

The 2nd and 3rd methods show native `AllAuth` form. If you need to edit it somehow using `{{form}}`, ->[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)<- in the doc you can find some examples how to do that. Want to mention, that if in the doc is shown something like:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    {{ form.subject.label_tag }}
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
```

for our case `form` must be changed to `loginctx` or `loginform`

Also you can write your own form or inherit `AllAuth` and import it to `context processor` or `templatetag` as shown above.

Both methods are based on ->[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606525/how-to-include-class-based-views-in-context-processors-in-django/34607875#34607875)<-

In all 3 methods redirect works as needed (return a user to the previous page, in case of success login, else redirect to original `AllAuth` template at `site.com/account/login`).

All written above can be implemented to SignUP.

Also I asked some people, how to show errors in case of wrong username\password instead of redirect to `site.com/account/login`, a proposition was to use `AJAX`, but currently this is out of my knowledge. Some base info about connection signin\up forms to default AllAuth views can be found ->[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162108/implementing-ajax-requests-response-with-django-allauth)<-. If anyone could implement it, or find any tutorial, please post it here.